# Выбрать атрибут для парсинга

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Здравствуйте. Использую Simple HTML DOM Parser

Каким образом получить данные из блока `<span data-type="time">ДАННЫЕ</span>`

```
$dan = $html->find('.time');
```

это работает для class

Comment: Simple HTML DOM Parser работает относительно медленно, если много работы возложено на парсер советовал бы от него отказаться.

Answer (score 1):

Следуйте общим правилам построения селекторов

```
$html->find('[data-type="time"]')
```